# DDNS and NetCat

Tags: netcat

I'm messing around with netcat(windows) and i'm trying to configure netcat listening to external connections.My ISP provides me dynamic IP so i gotta find a way to have netcat connecting back to me no matter if my IP changes within 2 or 3 days.
What i thought is that i could download a DDNS program which is attaching my dynamic IP to a static DNS name like whatever_dnsname.biz or something like that.I've done port forwarding on my router so i was just wondering if anyone knows the command that netcat could use to connect to that static DNS name of my choice.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- Check your router if it supports DDNS and make netcat connect to the ddns domain you have created as soon as your router gets new ip it will update Link: [Example](http://www.tp-link.com/gr/article/?faqid=297)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply Homer!! I'll try that as soon as possible!